# How to sort increment buttons in android studio

Tags: android

i have a voter app which has 5 increment buttons in mainactivity. lets say btn1 has 140 votes ,btn2 has 101 votes,btn3 has 155 votes ,btn4 has 133 votes and btn5 has 199.

now in other activity which is called result activity in that activity i want above votes by ascending order. meaning in this activity i want to display btn5-199 btn3-155 btn1-140 btn4-133 btn2-101 like this.

this is java code for increment counters.

````
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count10counter++;


            count10.saveTotalInPrefcount10 ( getApplicationContext (),count10counter );
            tvcount10.setText ( Integer.toString ( count10counter ) );

            Toast.makeText ( getApplicationContext (),"you clicked   10",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        }

    } );
    btncount11 = findViewById ( R.id.btncount11 );
    tvcount11 =findViewById ( R.id.tvcount11 );

    count11counter= count11.loadtotalfromprefkalyancount11 ( this );
    tvcount11.setText ( Integer.toString ( count11counter ) );

    btncount11.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count11counter++;
            count11.saveTotalInPrefcount11 ( getApplicationContext (),count11counter );
            tvcount11.setText ( Integer.toString ( count11counter ) );
            Toast.makeText ( getApplicationContext (),"you clicked   11",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        }
    } );

    btncount12 = findViewById ( R.id.btncount12 );
    tvcount12 =findViewById ( R.id.tvcount12 );

    count12counter= count12.loadtotalfromprefkalyancount12 ( this );
    tvcount12.setText ( Integer.toString ( count12counter ) );

    btncount12.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count12counter++;
            count12.saveTotalInPrefcount12 ( getApplicationContext (),count12counter );
            tvcount12.setText ( Integer.toString ( count12counter ) );
            Toast.makeText ( getApplicationContext (),"you clicked   12",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        }
    } );

    btncount13 = findViewById ( R.id.btncount13 );
    tvcount13 =findViewById ( R.id.tvcount13 );

    count13counter= count13.loadtotalfromprefkalyancount13 ( this );
    tvcount13.setText ( Integer.toString ( count13counter ) );

    btncount13.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count13counter++;
            count13.saveTotalInPrefcount13 ( getApplicationContext (),count13counter );
            tvcount13.setText ( Integer.toString ( count13counter ) );
            Toast.makeText ( getApplicationContext (),"you clicked   13",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        }
    } );
    btncount14 = findViewById ( R.id.btncount14 );
    tvcount14 =findViewById ( R.id.tvcount14 );

    count14counter= count14.loadtotalfromprefkalyancount14 ( this );
    tvcount14.setText ( Integer.toString ( count14counter ) );

    btncount14.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count14counter++;
            count14.saveTotalInPrefcount14 ( getApplicationContext (),count14counter );
            tvcount14.setText ( Integer.toString ( count14counter ) );
            Toast.makeText ( getApplicationContext (),"you clicked   14",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        }
    } );
    btncount15 = findViewById ( R.id.btncount15 );
    tvcount15 =findViewById ( R.id.tvcount15 );

    count15counter= count15.loadtotalfromprefkalyancount15 ( this );
    tvcount15.setText ( Integer.toString ( count15counter ) );

    btncount15.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count15counter++;
            count15.saveTotalInPrefcount15 ( getApplicationContext (),count15counter );
            tvcount15.setText ( Integer.toString ( count15counter ) );
            Toast.makeText ( getApplicationContext (),"you clicked   15",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        }
    } ); ```
````

Comment: Try sorting your array list on each button click and use `notifyDatasetChanged` method call for updation after sorting

Comment: This is pretty similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71431781/how-to-swap-elements-in-a-grid-layout-android/71432258#71432258) that I have previously answered. It might help.